# How to add a couple of custom exceptions and redirect all the rest of url-s to another url in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

There is two sites, **old.com** and **new.com**. In the .htaccess of old.com I have some **custom URL**'s that should be redirected like:

*1. example.html -> new/something/

2. example2 -> new/stgelse
3. example-3 -> new/another.html
4. /admin should not redirect anywhere.*

**All the rest** of url's of old.com should redirect **to new.com**(index).
So far I've achieved to manage to redirect everything regarding old.com to new.com, with `Redirect 301 / http://new.com/`.
I've tried to add exceptions, like writing `Redirect 301 something.html http://new.com/whatever`, but it just redirected to new.com(index).
Also, I've tried `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}`, but it seems like `Redirect 301 / http://new.com/` overwrites everything. How could I successfully apply my custom exceptions? I have like 5 of them only.

Even if I only try `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.new.com/$1 [R=301,L]`, then I navigate to old.com/admin, it redirect to the index of new.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix Redirect with RewriteRule they are two diffrent modules.

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

#example.html => http://newsite.com/new/something

RewriteRule ^example.html$ http://nesite.com/new/something/ [L,R]
#example2.html => http://newsite.com/new/another.html
RewriteRule ^example2.html$ http://newsite.com/new/another.html [L,R]
#redirect everything except /admin
RewriteRule !^admin http://newsite.com/ [L,R]
```

Comment: It's great for the exceptions, they work they way they should be, but unfortunately it doesn't recognise the admin exception. I was thinking, to add admin as `RewriteRule ^admin http://newsite.com/admin [L,R]`, but then again I should write a "rewrite all to new.com", and I'm afraid it would redirect everything there again.

Comment: This does exclude the /admin, I think you are have a browser cache related issue. Clear your cache or try a diffrent browser to test this.

Comment: My code looks like `RewriteRule !^admin https://new.com/ [L,R]` and it doesn't exclude the admin, even if I clear cache, or watch it in incognito mode, it still redirects from /admin to new.com, I cannot access the backend of the old site now.

Comment: I've even tried to add `RewriteRule ^admin [L]` to the top of all rules, and it still redirects to new.com...

Comment: Is /admin a subfolder?

Comment: I don't think so, I can't see it as a subfolder. We're talking about a Magento webshop by the way.

Comment: I've just tried `RewriteRule !^/admin/(.*)/?$ https://www.priss.dk/ [L,R=301]` like at subfolders, but still redirects to new.com...

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the answer regarding the way to add exceptions is already given. It might be a full answer at other cases, but in the case of Magento the final condition, "everything else should redirect to new.com except admin" looks the following way:

```html
## RewriteRule !^/admin https://www.new.com/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin(/|$)
RewriteRule ^([\w/]*)$ http://www.new.com [L]
```

The first, commented condition is true only for precise "admin", but at Magento the admin might get pre- or appended, without showing anything else than "admin" in the navbar. This way it works perfectly.